# From what pool is the weekly newsletter created?

Tags: discussion, newsletter, top-questions

I just got the meta weekly newsletter and lo and behold the top questions from the past **2 hours** are on the *Top new questions this week:* list.

Shouldn't some older questions have priority?

Why do I need to see in a newsletter that        [How does SOPA threaten Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114005/155556) and [Please do not use Stack Overflow to promote social causes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/155556) are top questions??

They are from the last hour?!

Does the newsletter algorithm assume that the user is not online?

If so, what pool of questions does it see as **`Top`**?

Comment: They sure do look "hot"

Comment: @random that is true. but `hot` for the whole week?

Answer (score 1):

Newsletters use the [*week* sort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) to get "top new questions".

Comment: how does that tab sort the questions?