# Why doesn't Stack Exchange move outside the US to protect itself from SOPA?

Tags: discussion, sopa

I'm from Lebanon, and don't know anything about the US. I read the system message we all read, did some research and found out that it's nothing but a good thing. That made my day!

I wondered how SOPA would affect this site, and then I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/how-does-sopa-threaten-stack-overflow).

Why doesn't Stack Exchange host the sites outside of the USA? Every big company in my country hosts its sites, including big sites like those owned by telecommunication companies, offshore instead of having servers here.

I and my friend, for example, created a site where we serve pirated music. I don't care about copyright laws. My site is hosted offshore, so I'm untouchable.

What do I mean by "offshore"? Somewhere like Russia or Ukraine. You know how it is in those countries... they don't care about the law.

99.9% of Stack Overflow users are professionals, so if the USA doesn't allow its citizens to use SO, they can use a proxy.

No one can stop hacking. The Chinese are hacking billions of dolalrs from banks and the USA is not able to do anything. I heard that from an official in the Secret Service responsible for Internet security on National Geographic TV. Hacking is the reason why people in Lebanon study computer science. It is the reason why I became interested in programming. No one can stop it. When will your government understand that?

**Who can kill all the bugs in this world?**

Comment: Because if we ran away every time something threatened our existence, the world would be a terrible place?

Comment: my cousin is a software engineer i asked him why he didn't study ethical hacking - he said: "i don't want to fight in a war that never ends - if you want to hack my site you can hack it, i just want to have fun programming."

Comment: This was already discussed in various comments on the existing SOPA questions, but here's the summary: 1) many people think SOPA is morally and/or ethically wrong; 2) the country SE moves to could implement a similar law; 3) the site might continue to exist, but it would be harder (and possibly illegal) to get to, and become less valuable as people left.

Comment: @Bart no no, if you are not hosting in Usa they will lose $$ companies will be closed - you'll teach them a lesson - they care about the money - not about you - if u didn't pay for apple - free mp3 downloads would be legal - if you stand together and make them lose their money - they will die

Comment: I'm sure all the people who provide you with free content are extremely happy with you.

Comment: **why so many downvotes for this question?** It is a good question! And **it is not a proposal** to do so, so what you downvoters disagree with? How can you disagre with a question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is [mentioned elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114051/59303) and the answer is that the act would

> ... require[s] ISPs to block DNS lookups for companies that it considers to be offending, and it requires banks to prevent payment transfers to those companies.

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114051/59303)

So relocating to outside the US wouldn't help.

Comment: Well yeah it would - it would mean that non-US residents (that have non-US IPSs) would still be able to access Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Kragen - I would suspect that the US is still by far the largest user base, so cutting off *those* users would mean that the sites wouldn't survive.