# If the SOPA message is so important, why isn't it displayed on the other sites?

Tags: discussion, system-message, sopa

I suppose this is the opposite of [complaining about too much use of the system-status banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes)...

If something is so sinister that it [threatens the very existence of the StackExchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114007/157384), why isn't the banner displayed on other SE-network sites?  (I've only seen it on SO)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is displayed on *some* of the other sites, they just don't use the banner. Also no notice was given to mods of other sites of placing a banner up.

<sub>(because that's not what the banner is supposed to be used for nevertheless we will call this *exception #2*)</sub>.

They are displayed instead as Community Promotion Ads. This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site.

Super User

[image: Have Joel explain it to you.]

Gaming

[image: Really... have Joel explain it to you.]

I am not sure about the other sites. These ads were designed by [badp](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13992/badp).

Maybe we can ask him kindly to make ads (or the source image file) for the rest of sites if he is not too busy.

Comment: The problem is Gaming and SU are the only sites out there that have adequate community-driven advertisement programs. SO's, for example, is reserved to FOSS projects.

Comment: @badp Where did you get that? [Lots of sites have the ad posts](http://stackexchange.com/filters/27749/community-promotion-ads); I think most of them include the option for "anything else your community would genuinely be interested in"

Comment: Well I posted one to the SO community ads and was informed that while the sentiment was appreciated, _only_ FOSS ads were permitted, so the ad was removed.