# Would it be possible to organize the stackoverflow community to oppose SOPA?

Tags: discussion, sopa

While I realize this is a technical Q & A site, many normally non-political organizations, including the Internet Society and Wikipedia are either opposing or considering opposing the bill, so I wonder if Stack Overflow might be organized to do the same.

There seems to be already a pretty strong consensus that SOPA is bad for SO, so we might also issue a community letter to Congress.

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/protect-intellectual-property-but-not-like-this/

Comment: I find it amazing how much of an impact reddit had after they put a small fight censorship banner on their logo. I agree with Merlin2011

Comment: I personally don't think it would be off topic to draft a CW letter as an answer to this question. This topic is decidedly _about_ Stack Overflow. Don't forget the chat system is available for extended discussion.

Comment: Additionally, something like [this](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2011/12/internet-inventors-warn-against-sopa-and-pipa) seems like a good guide for writing one.

Comment: There should definitely be a banner displayed about this across the top of StackOverflow.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't Hmm... [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes) [sounds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114203/why-has-the-sopa-banner-disappeared-from-the-site-header) [familiar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114130/if-the-sopa-message-is-so-important-why-isnt-it-displayed-on-the-other-sites)...